# Relocation error with libstdc++.so.6

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, libstdc++

My task is to port a set of closed source libraries from Windows/MSVC2013 to Ubuntu Linux 12.04/64 with gcc. I have already compiled and installed gcc5.2 (needed for "official" C++11 support) which also replaced the libstdc++ libs with libstdc++.so.6.0.21.

My library uses - among others - the great log4cplus logging framework. This is the first part I want to port, and I have already succeeded with:

- build the log4cplus shared library
- deploy the log4cplus shared library to /usr/local/lib and run sudo ldconfig
- build the static library dependent on log4cplus (which basically puts some syntactic sugar around log4cplus)
- build the test application and link it to the static library

When I use the -static-libstdc++ compiler option for g++ to compile log4cplus, my test application starts and works fine. However, this is not the final solution (closed source). When I omit the option in the log4cplus makefile I get the following error running my app:

```
BasicsTests: relocation error: /usr/local/lib/liblog4cplusU.so.0: symbol _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEED1Ev, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I have used the readelf tool to find out if this symbol is really missing / wrong version but apparently this is not the case:

```
$ readelf -s --wide /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEED1Ev
  4858: 000000000010cd10   108 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEED1Ev@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21
  6042: 000000000010cd10   108 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   11 _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEED1Ev
```

And my test application is a 64 bit executable file, so I would expect it to link to that library:

```
$ file BasicsTests 
BasicsTests: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, not stripped
```

I am not sure which particular so library the relocation is targeting (I have other libstdc++ versions on the system, but none of them is older than 6.0.19, plus they are located in directories which I suspect to be application specific).

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

just gives me nothing, so no paths other than the standards should apply

Apart from the error which I cannot explain, the thing that puzzles me is that no (link to) libstdc++.so is located in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib, however, the library appears to be found (I see different errors when the library cannot be found).

I apologize if I ask stupid questions / have made stupid mistakes, but I am new to development under Linux and this investigation is the result of my frustrating jump start into that field in the last few days.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** - question by Oleksandr Kravchuk

/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf contents:

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is you link your binary with one libstdc++ and Linux's dynamic linker uses another one. That is why static linking makes your program work.

You can fix it by commenting out unnecessary copies of the library in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf and running ldconfig afterwords.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is just two lines: # libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib, see my edit above. But I appreciate the hint. Maybe I missed ld configuration files.. However grep-ing for libstdc++ through all files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ does not show any result. Will dig deeper into this

Comment: @kritzel_sw exactly! but you're compiling with the one located in /usr/local/lib64/

Comment: @kritzel_sw to check if this is the issue, run the following command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/ ./you_bin_file`

Comment: Not sure if I get your point. The one in /usr/local/lib64 seems correct, and I do not have a lib or a symlink in /usr/local/lib. The only libraries in /usr/local/lib are my own log4cplus libraries...

Comment: AWESOME! It works! Thank you soo much! I have just registered today, so I cannot upvote your post, but I will come back and do this as soon as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: @kritzel_sw: You will be able to _accept_ it, though.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Thanks for the hint. Did it and upvoted. Great first contact with stackoverflow as a registered user! Kudos to the team